# Descobrir array keys de um vetor

Tags: php

Tenho um array onde os índices "pais" não são indexados com underlines e os filhos sim. Toda vez que algum pai recebe um filho, todos os outros pais também recebem um filho.

Exemplo temos 2 filhos:

```
array(
  x = array()
  x_1 = array()
  x_2 = array()
  y = array()
  y_1 = array()
  y_2 = array()
);
```

Eu preciso pegar todos os índices que são pais, nesse caso x e y.
A solução que encontrei seria percorrer o vetor buscando índices que não tem underline, mas não achei uma solução bonita, pois eu teria que percorrer mais uma vez o vetor para adicionar filhos novos.

Alguém teria uma solução mais simples e/ou mais bonita?

Comment: Você já analisou a seguinte lógica $array( 'pai1' => array( 'filho1', 'filho2' ), pai2 => array('filho1', 'filho2') ), acho que ficaria melhor que a lógica descrita em seu exemplo acima, desta forma não precisa percorrer o array, só colocar o indice pai e o número correspondente do pai.

Comment: Já sim @duque, mas essa forma ja foi implementada, eu não tenho mais essa opção

Comment: Então rapaz, desta forma você vai ser obrigado a percorrer todo o array buscando os indices sem o underscore.

Comment: Se você só precisa pegar os indicies não precisa de loop. Precisará apenas para pegar as informações do tal índice.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `preg_filter` para isso, assim filtrar apenas por onde "não houver" o underline, ou qualquer outro caractere.

Por padrão o `regex` retorna apenas dados que existem, mas há forma de inverter isto.

**Bem, no geral é isso:**

```
<?php

// Sua array!
$array = array(
  'x' => array(),
  'x_1' => array(),
  'x_2' => array(),
  'y' => array(),
  'y_1' => array(),
  'y_2' => array(),
);

// Filtro para apenas sem _
$filtro = preg_filter('/^((?!_).)*$/', '$1', array_keys( $array ));

// Exibe o $filtro
print_r($filtro);
```

O retorno será:

```
Array ( [0] => x [3] => y )
```

[Você pode testar isto clicando aqui!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b1d7e2cc19534e82549f487882f6ab89b293253)